# Where can I find the SCR file for HP Fortify?

Tags: fortify

I have the following error popping up when I try to run HP Fortify on my RAD 7.5 developer tool's project.

[image]

This is because it cannot find the SCA executable file.

Where do I need to point my developer to in the file directory for it to find the SCA?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've figured it out.

First of all, when installing HP Fortify, I have to make sure to include the Eclipse Plugin.  This I was already doing.

Second, after installation when running my first Scan, I have to locate the 'scourceanalyzer.exe' file on my computer.

In a standard installation to the C drive, the location of the file will be:

**C:\Program Files\HP_Fortify\HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_4.00\bin\sourceanalyzer.exe**

You'll have to select "OK" when the second image I posted in this question pops up (the one that asks you if you want to locate the SCA Executable), and then you will have to navigate to the address of that file manually and select it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might need to re-install.

Comment: I did, though it's a little more complicated than that.